# $concat two fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this two collections:

```
employees :  {_id: NumberInt(0), name:"Max",surname:"Power"}, ..
```

and

```
loggableUser:{_id: NumberInt(0), employee: NumberInt(1), ..},
```

Now I have to insert into the following query a field "fullName" containing "employee.name" + " " + "employee.surname".
I tried this query:

```
db.loggableUser.aggregate([
    {
      '$lookup':
      {
        'from': 'employees',
        'localField': 'employee',
        'foreignField' : '_id',
        'as': 'employee'
      }
    },
    { "$addFields":{ 
         "$employee.fullName" : "$employee.name" + " " + "$employee.surname"}])
```

but it does not work.
I know is a simple thing but I can't get it works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `employee` then you can use [**`$concat`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to combine two fields.

```
db.loggableUser.aggregate([
  { '$lookup': {
    'from': 'employees',
    'localField': 'employee',
    'foreignField' : '_id',
    'as': 'employee'
  }},
  { '$unwind': '$employee' },
  { '$addFields': { 
    'employee.fullName' : { '$concat': ['$employee.name', ' ', '$employee.surname'] }
  }}
])
```

Which is far easier with the mongodb **3.6** and above [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax.

```
db.loggableUser.aggregate([
  { '$lookup': {
    'from': 'employees',
    'let': { 'employee': '$employee' },
    'pipeline': [
      { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': ['$_id', '$$employee'] }}},
      { '$addFields': { 'fullName' : { '$concat': ['$name', ' ', '$surname'] }}}
    ]
    'as': 'employee'
  }}
])
```

Comment: Instead of plus sign use `,`

Comment: Yes, all field show up correctly but the new field "fullName" is null.

Comment: try with { '$addFields': { 'fullName' : { '$concat': ['$$employee.name', ' ', '$$employee.surname'] }}}

Comment: @matthPen No man!!! `$` is used for the document fields and `$$` is used for the variables