# mongo update query not working for older version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below query works fine for mongo version 4.2, but when I run the same query on the older version it is an error -"The dollar `($)` prefixed field `$concat` in `GUID.$concat` is not valid for storage".

```
db.getCollection('xxxx').update(
    { "SHARE": false },
    [{ 
        "$set": { 
            "GUID": { 
                "$concat": [
                    { $toString: "$ID" }, 
                    { $toString: "$DATE" }
                ] 
            } 
        } 
    }],
    { 
        upsert: false,
        multi: true 
    }
)
```

Is there any way to modify the above query in older mongo version.

Comment: yes this is from 4.2, you can not use in older version. [update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: can that help your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326901/concat-two-fields-in-mongodb?

Comment: With older versions (pre MongoDB 4.2) you can update using two operations - first the aggregation (using `$concat`, etc.) and then an update.

Comment: Your update query will update documents which are the result of the aggregation. Check your aggregation result, first and then update.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for the help. below query works for me.

db.getCollection('xxxx').aggregate([
   {$addFields: { GUID: { $concat: [ {$toString:"$ID"} ] }}}
]).forEach
(
   function(x)
   {
       db.getCollection('xxxx').update({"_id":x._id},{$set:{GUID:x.GUID}},{multi:true});
       //print((x._id.toString()))
   }
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query works for me,

db.getCollection('xxxx').aggregate([ {$addFields: { GUID: { $concat: [ {$toString:"$ID"} ] }}} ]).forEach ( function(x) { db.getCollection('xxxx').update({"_id":x._id},{$set:{GUID:x.GUID}},{multi:true}); //print((x._id.toString())) } )